# Stripe / Rails problem : Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, stripe-payments

Hello i'm building a site where i'm implementing plans and subscriptions with stripe in order to sign up.

I don't know what changed but my site was working properly and then i started getting this error and i've tried several things but i can't fix it.

**This is the error i'm getting**

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Users::RegistrationsController#create
Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string. See API docs at https://stripe.com/docs'
Extracted source (around line #28):

26   def save_with_subscription
27    if valid?
28       customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)  
29       self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
30       save!
31    end
```

This is my javascript file **intensive_plan.js**

```js
/* global $, Stripe */
//Document ready.
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  var theFormIntensive = $('#intensive_form');
  var submitBtnIntensive = $('#form-signup-btn-intensive');
  //Set Stripe public key.
  Stripe.setPublishableKey( $('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content') );
  //When user clicks form submit btn,
  submitBtnIntensive.click(function(event){
    //prevent default submission behavior.
    event.preventDefault();
    submitBtnIntensive.val("Procesando").prop('disabled', true);
    //Collect the credit card fields.
    var ccNum = $('#card_number').val(),
        cvcNum = $('#card_code').val(),
        expMonth = $('#card_month').val(),
        expYear = $('#card_year').val();
    //Use Stripe JS library to check for card errors.
    var error = false;
    //Validate card number.
    if(!Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(ccNum)) {
      error = true;
      alert('The credit card number appears to be invalid');
    }
    //Validate CVC number.
    if(!Stripe.card.validateCVC(cvcNum)) {
      error = true;
      alert('The CVC number appears to be invalid');
    }
    //Validate expiration date.
    if(!Stripe.card.validateExpiry(expMonth, expYear)) {
      error = true;
      alert('The expiration date appears to be invalid');
    }
    if (error) {
      //If there are card errors, don't send to Stripe.
      submitBtnIntensive.prop('disabled', false).val("Sign Up");
    } else {
      //Send the card info to Stripe.
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: ccNum,
        cvc: cvcNum,
        exp_month: expMonth,
        exp_year: expYear
      }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }
    return false;
  });
  //Stripe will return a card token.
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    //Get the token from the response.
    var token = response.id;
    //Inject the card token in a hidden field.
    theFormIntensive.append( $('<input type="hidden" name="user[stripe_card_token]">').val(token) );
    //Submit form to our Rails app.
    theFormIntensive.get(0).submit();
  }
});
```

This is my **user.rb** model file

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan
  ############################################################################################
  ## PeterGate Roles                                                                        ##
  ## The :user role is added by default and shouldn't be included in this list.             ##
  ## The :root_admin can access any page regardless of access settings. Use with caution!   ##
  ## The multiple option can be set to true if you need users to have multiple roles.       ##
  petergate(roles: [:site_admin], multiple: false)                                      ##
  ############################################################################################ 


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable


  validates_presence_of :name

  # If pro user passes validations (email,password, etc..),
  # then call Stripe and tell Stripe to set up a subscription
  # upon charging the customer's card.
  # Sripe responds back with customer data.
  # Store customer.id as the customer token and save the user.
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token
  def save_with_subscription
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: email, plan: plan_id, source: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end

  def first_name
    self.name.split.first

  end

  def last_name
    self.name.split.last
  end

end
```

I believe thatthe main problem is that i'm not getting back the stripe_card_token from stripe and the value is empty but i don't know what to do, any ideas?

Comment: your assumption is reasonable and I'm fairly sure that's what happened. I haven't seen Stripe docs but my suggestion is you should handle unsuccessful Stripe call more gracefully ie not submitting the form if token is not found :)

Comment: thanks i'll do that :)